# Container manager keep terminate container on signal 9

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am trying to play with Google Cloud Run, I have the same service that works fine in App Engine Flex.  Any thoughts what could be the issue?

[image]

Somehow it shows that service is healthy.

[image]

Comment: Google Cloud Run doesn’t keep your applications alive forever. Inactive services are currently killed with SIGKILL (9).

Comment: thank you @AhmetB-Google is there option to add `readiness_check` or sort of `readinessProbe `on GKE?  So I can keep container running?

Comment: Please open a new question to ask it. This question is very unrelated to your original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means infrastructure (container manager) scales down the number instances when traffic drops.

It's safe to ignore.

Comment: Hmmm... in case I have service that works with `pub/sub` only. I need it running how to handle that?

Comment: Cloud run works with pub sub push subscription, does it work for you? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub

Comment: ehh... it is not efficient for me. I need a pull subscription.

Comment: Cloud Run doesn't keep long running instances, therefore it doesn't work with pull subscription currently

Comment: This can also mean your container ran out of resources and was killed. I wouldn't recommend ignoring it.

Answer (score 3):

For others who find this question when their container didn't start the first time you deployed it: It's important to note that you need to have it listening on the environment variable `PORT`.

It appears that Cloud Run will dynamically map your container to a port at invocation, and the service that you're running needs to (dynamically) use this to serve it's content.

For reference, here's how I got the base Apache Docker image to work with Cloud Run to host a static site built via Node:

```
FROM node:lts AS build
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM httpd:latest
ENV PORT=80
RUN sed -i 's/80/${PORT}/g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY --from=build ./dist/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Comment: Actually, the `ENV PORT=80` is to set a _default_ (if one is not specified). Cloud Run will specify a port, always, so this default will only be used if you are running the container locally (or elsewhere). This is indeed a working example that I currently use for several (at least 3) websites. I suspect that you need to take a closer look at you NGINX config to see if it is using an environment variable for it's port listening (since it can be quite different from Apache).

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because billing was disabled
Make sure billing is enabled on your GCP project

https://console.cloud.google.com/billing